# How to cross-build external (out-of-tree) kernel module for another Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, kernel, arm64, cross-compilation

I can find proper guidelines anywhere how to cross-compile an external module on Ubuntu for another Ubuntu on ARM64. I had to remove `-mrecord-mcount` from CFLAGS for the process as none of recent `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` cross compilers seem to support this option.

But then I'm hitting the following error:

```
./include/uapi/linux/types.h:5:10: fatal error: asm/types.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
    5 | #include <asm/types.h>
```

(what actually rings bell why `gcc-multilib` is not allowed with cross compilers)

Other cross compilations worked for me so far. I wonder what package for `arm64` architecture I'd need to install for `asm/types.h` to appear in `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/`?

---

`Makefile`:

```
obj-m := module.o
ovaone-objs += modmain.o mod-controls.o
ccflags-remove-y += -mrecord-mcount

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all default: modules
install: modules_install

modules modules_install help clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(shell pwd) $@
```

---

Adding `ccflags-y += -I/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include` to the above `Makefile` leads to the following error:

```
./arch/arm64/include/asm/alternative-macros.h:8:10: fatal error: asm/cpucaps.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
    8 | #include <asm/cpucaps.h>
```

and I can't find such file in the **WHOLE** system, meaning something is missing. The only sensible reference is [this kernel patch discussion](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20210429123243.GA15092@arm.com/T/).